# AWS WorkSpace client will not use certificate

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have multiple AWS WorkSpaces for every member in my team and I have restricted access to use a certificate. I have added the root certificate into the AWS management console and generated .p12 files for all the users. Mac users can import the root, intermediate and their .p12 files into Keychain Access and AWS WS works fine and allows them to log in. However Windows users have imported the same three files into their cert store using mmc.exe, certmgr.msc, and by clicking the certificates individually and importing that in that way, but this is not working. Every time a user tries to open AWS WS client it says you're not authorised. I have tired using a known working .p12 file but it just doesn't work for windows users. Does anybody have any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Are the certificates stored in 'Personal -> Certificates'?

Comment: Yeah they are. The root is stored in the Trusted Root folder, and I have tried to put the intermediate in the both the personal and the intermediated folder.

Comment: hey @GBSingh were you able to solve this ?